# SyntaxError: missing ; before statement?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript, and am trying add elements to an empty array inside an object, but it keeps saying that I'm missing a semicolon. Here's my object:

```
var ssbbScores = {names: ["N", "B", "J"], scores: []}
```

Here's where I try to add an element to scores:

```
ssbbScores.score[0] = 7;
```

What am I doing wrong, I have a semicolon right there?

Comment: What is giving you this message? Where does it say the semi-colon is missing from?

Comment: `.score[0]` should be giving you `cannot set property '0' of undefined` since you declared it as `scores`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a semicolon after the first line, but the problem is that the key is `scores` and you try to access it with `score`.

You are missing the final `s` .

```
ssbbScores.scores[0] = 7;
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget an s in the attribute

```
var ssbbScores = {names: ["N", "B", "J"], scores: []}; 
ssbbScores.scores[0] = 7;//scores and note score
```